# Recursive function to parse XML document using Symfony's DomCrawler component

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symfony 5.2 & [DomCrawler component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

I have this XML file like :

```
<product>
   <ref>32332</ref>
   <name>Test 1</name>
   <features>
       <feature>
           <name>Feature 1</name>
           <value>Red</value>
       </feature>
       <feature>
           <name>Feature 2</name>
           <value>Large</value>
       </feature>
   </features>
</product>
```

I want to get an array like:

```
$array = [
    'ref' => 32332,
    'name' => 'Test 1',
    'features' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Feature 1',
            'value' => 'Red',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Feature 2',
            'value' => 'Large',
        ]
     ]
];
```

I want a kind of recursive function, I made this:

```
/**
 * @param DOMElement $child
 * @param $array
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function recursiveNode(DOMElement $child)
{
    if ($child->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach ($child->childNodes as $childNode) {
            if ($childNode->hasChildNodes()) {
                $array [] = Xml::recursiveNode($childNode);
            } else {
                $array [$childNode->nodeName] = $childNode->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $array [$child->nodeName] = $child->nodeValue;
    }

    return $array;
}
```

I called like this:

```
$products = $crawler->filterXPath('PRODUCTS/PRODUCT');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    /** @var DOMElement $child */
    foreach ($product->childNodes as $child) {
        $output = Xml::recursiveNode($child);
    }
}
```

But it clearly doesn't work, I have an array of array of array... how can I make this array?

Comment: Doesn't [`simplexml_load_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string) produce something similar enough to what you need?

Comment: I wanted to try this Symfony's component, but maybe you are right, it looks simpler to use

Answer (score -2):

The PHP function [`simplexml_load_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string) loads the XML into an object of type [`SimpleXMLElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) that can be then queried for values very similar to the way an object is inspected for properties.

If you need the data in a plain array then it can be done using a simple trick: encode the `SimplXMLElement` as JSON then decode the JSON back to a simple data structure and pass `true` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get arrays, not objects:

```php
$xml = <<< END
<product>
   <ref>32332</ref>
   <name>Test 1</name>
   <features>
       <feature>
           <name>Feature 1</name>
           <value>Red</value>
       </feature>
       <feature>
           <name>Feature 2</name>
           <value>Large</value>
       </feature>
   </features>
</product>
END;

$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true));
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/R1hq7)